# Rails grouped_collection_select not working when saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `grouped_collection_select` in filtering out associated information in a rails 5 form.

The first `grouped_collection_select` works with the **Property** filtering out associated data relevant to **Co-operators**. But, the second `grouped_collection_select` does work when filtering **Fields** associated to a **Property**, but comes up with an error when trying to save:

```
1 error prohibited this trial from being saved:

Field must exist
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: trial, local: true) do |f| %>
 <label>Co-operator</label>
 <%= f.collection_select :cooperator_id, Cooperator.order('last_name'), :id, :full_name %>
 <label>Property</label>
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select :property_id, Cooperator.order('last_name'), :properties, :full_name, :cooperator_id, :name %>
 <label>Field</label>
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select :field_id, Property.order('name'), :fields, :name, :property_id, :field_name %>
 <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

When I change the `grouped_collection_select` to a `collection_select` it works as should. But, this does't suit what i'm needing.

```
<%= f.collection_select :field_id, Field.all, :id, :field_name %>
```

**Trials Controller**

```
def trial_params
 params.require(:trial).permit(:cooperator_id, :field_id, :property_id)
end
```

**Trial Model**

```
class Trial < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cooperator
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :field
end
```

**Log**

```
Processing by TrialsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"THfy+JGBYbNvzurUscPfP8LQbnnvIz1HBEfeFRiZrocXtiu4ayncEA8cNBA2IkPgcphLoa0QWsEueFBEP29OXA==", "trial"=>{"cooperator_id"=>"2", "property_id"=>"2", "field_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create trial", "id"=>"11"}
Cooperator Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "cooperators".* FROM "cooperators" WHERE "cooperators"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trials_controller.rb:49
  Property Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/trials_controller.rb:49
Field Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "fields".* FROM "fields"
  ↳ app/views/trials/_form.html.erb:39
Rendered trials/_form.html.erb (15.3ms)
  Rendered trials/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (16.6ms)
  Rendered partials/_top_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered partials/_main_nav.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 46.9ms | ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)
```

Comment: why do you using this at the field control end ":field_name, :field_name %>"   as you can see in control above  you wrote ":cooperator_id, :name %>
 <label>Field</label>"   so I suggest you to try on field control to change to ":field_id, :field_name %>"

Comment: also what are the fields for Cooperator and Property?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Have updated it.

Comment: Update the question with the Trial model with associations and also with relevant controller code

Comment: Also update the question with the params that appear in the server log when you submit the form

Comment: Thanks @Pavan I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok, the `field_id` is coming as nil. Can you inspect the HTML of the `grouped_collection_select` in the bowser's console and paste in the question?

Comment: I wonder why you have `Property.order('name')` for the **collection** in the `grouped_collection_select` and `Field.all` for the **collection** in the `collection_select`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form code doesn't look right to me, the first grouped collection should be something like:

`<%= f.grouped_collection_select :property_id, Cooperator.order('last_name'), :properties, :full_name, :id, :name %>` # Notice that the `cooperator_id` is replaced with `id` because this needs to be the value that should be set on selection. Your original code would set it to the ID of the Cooperator instead of Property.

Similarly, the second one should be something like:

`<%= f.grouped_collection_select :field_id, Property.order('name'), :fields, :name, :id, :field_name %>`

Comment: Yep. That did it @chirag. Changing the :property_id to :id worked.